# Transfer a data along with dependencies

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, import

Is it possible to transfer a data along with dependencies?

For example I have database1 and database2 with same schema.

Database1 contain records while database2 is an empty database.

I want to transfer a number of records from table1 from database1 going to table1 of database2.

But since table1 have foreign key constraint to table2 I could not move the data. Is it possible that I can move the dependency from table2 to database2 when I move the table1? Or it must be done manually?

Comment: you want to transfer only 'some of the records' but you want to have a similar data structure? Try to use import and export table. Then you might have the same data structure

Comment: would that possible in import and export table to have only 20 data for example?

Comment: Here is some reference you might need. You can query it on the option to limit the data and select what you wanted. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2012/01/09/exporting-selected-tables-from-a-sql-database.aspx

Comment: database2 already contains the same schema with database1

Comment: By the time you export the table you should also export the data. I am not sure if there is any method to export the data automatically for 2 table.